# Is there is option to mention TransactionModeas managed property in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, openjpa

I moved to Hibernate Persistence instead of open JPA persistence providerIMPL due to Jboss eap 6.4 open JPA issue earlier in persistence.xml  it is mentioned as below for OPEN JPA

```
        <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"></property> 
         <property name="openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode" value="always"/>
```

Now I changed to HibernatePersistence and added hibernatec3p0 properties instead of above property.

```
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
         <jta-data-source>pac</jta-data-source> 
       <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" 
      value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" /> 

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
```

Now my doubt is the above Hibernate c3p0 property solve OpenJPA transaction mode "managed" and connectionRetainmode "always".

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. JPA works fine in EAP 6.4. what issue due you have?

Comment: Currently I am using OpenJPA its given openJPA.main method No such method exception becuase jboss using default hibernate persistence